# How to annotate inside the plot when using datetime on the X axis with ggplot2?

Tags: r

I have successfully created a line a graph in R using **ggplot2** with percentage on **Y axis** and Date/Time on the X axis, but I am unsure how to annotate inside the graph for specific **date/time** points when their is a **high/low peak**.

The examples I identified (on R-bloggers & RPubs) are annotated without using date/time, and I have made attempts to annotate it (with ggtext and annotate functions, etc), but got nowhere. **Please can you show me an example of how to do this using ggplot2 in R?**

The current R code below creates the line graph, but can you help me extend the code to annotate inside of the graph?

```
sentimentdata <- read.csv("sentimentData-problem.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sentimentTime <- sentimentdata %>%
        filter(between(Hour, 11, 23)) 

sentimentTime$Datetime <- ymd_hm(sentimentTime$Datetime)

library(zoo)

sentimentTime %>%
  filter(Cat %in% c("Negative", "Neutral", "Positive")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Datetime, y = Percent, group = Cat, colour = Cat)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hours"), labels = date_format("%H:00")) +
  labs(title="Peak time on day of event", colour = "Sentiment Category") +
  xlab("By Hour") +
  ylab("Percentage of messages")
```

Data source available via GitHub:

Comment: Please give a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MartinGal done as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple lines and you want two labels on each line according to the maxima and minima, you could create two small dataframes to pass to `geom_text` calls.

First we ensure the necessary packages and the data are loaded:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

url <- paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcool12/",
              "datasets/master/sentimentData-problem.csv")

sentimentdata          <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sentimentdata$Datetime <- dmy_hm(sentimentdata$Datetime)
sentimentTime          <- filter(sentimentdata, between(Hour, 11, 23))
```

Now we can create a `max_table` and `min_table` that hold the x and y co-ordinates and the labels for our maxima and minima:

```
max_table <- sentimentTime %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarise(Datetime = Datetime[which.max(Percent)],
            Percent = max(Percent) + 3, 
            label = paste(trunc(Percent, 3), "%"))

min_table <- sentimentTime %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarise(Datetime = Datetime[which.min(Percent)],
            Percent = min(Percent) - 3, 
            label = paste(trunc(Percent, 3), "%"))
```

Which allows us to create our plot without much trouble:

```
sentimentTime %>%
  filter(Cat %in% c("Negative", "Neutral", "Positive")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Datetime, y = Percent, group = Cat, colour = Cat)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_text(data = min_table, aes(label = label)) +     # minimum labels
    geom_text(data = max_table, aes(label = label)) +     # maximum labels
    scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hours"), 
                     labels = date_format("%H:00")) +
    labs(title="Peak time on day of event", colour = "Sentiment Category") +
    xlab("By Hour") +
    ylab("Percentage of messages")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for making this example, really appreciate it. I have done what you asked, and provided info for reproducible example.

Comment: @jr134 I have completely rewritten my answer to make it directly applicable to your problem

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this, really big help.

Comment: I was wondering if I wanted more than two labels for each line according to the maxima and minima, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: @jr134 the easiest way is to create a data frame with the positions and labels you need then call an extra `geom_text` using this data frame.